# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this error `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')` when running my test, my test case can't make it past a line in my code and I'm not sure how to test for it, every time I comment out that line my test returns the result I want but with the line in I get the error below, how do I test for this in react?

Upon debugging I realised that `contentType` is undefined but I don't know how to test for that in my test, any help would be appreciated.

error message in full

```
 ● display data › should render data 

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')

      24 |   const lastIndex = currentPage * productsPerPage;
      25 |   const firstIndex = lastIndex - productsPerPage;
    > 26 |     const productsByContentType = products.filter((type: Products) => type.contentType.includes(contentTypeValue))  || products;
         |                                                                                        ^
      27 |   const filteredProducts = sortBy?.[filterValue]?.(productsByContentType) ?? productsByContentType;
      28 |
      29 |   const productsBySearchValue = filteredProducts.filter((search: Products) => {
```

my test is as follows:

```
describe('display data', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('should render data', async () => {
    const mAxiosResponse = {
      data: [{title: "5-Minute Stories: In the Wild"}],
    } as AxiosResponse;
    jest.spyOn(axios, 'get').mockResolvedValueOnce(mAxiosResponse);
    render(<Landing />);
    expect(screen.getByText('Loading...')).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(await screen.findByDisplayValue('Name:')).toBeInTheDocument();
    
  });
});
```

and the component I'm testing

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Suspense } from 'react';
import { sortBy, sortSelectOptions } from '../utils/utils';
import { Products } from '../types/types';
import { LazyLoadImage } from 'react-lazy-load-image-component';
import { fetchData } from '../endpoints/fetchData';
import axios, {AxiosResponse} from 'axios';
import { NoResults } from './NoResults';
import PlaceholderImage from '../../assets/spinner.gif';

import Select from './Select';
import TextInput from './TextInput';
import Pagination from './Pagination';
import '../index.css';

function App() {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState<Products[]>([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState<number>(1);
  const [filterValue, setFilterValue] = useState<string>('');
  
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState<string>('');
  const [contentTypeValue, setContentTypeValue] = useState<string>('Stories');

  const productsPerPage = 20;
  const lastIndex = currentPage * productsPerPage;
  const firstIndex = lastIndex - productsPerPage;
    const productsByContentType = products.filter((type: Products) => type.contentType.includes(contentTypeValue))  || products;
  const filteredProducts = sortBy?.[filterValue]?.(productsByContentType) ?? productsByContentType;
  
  const productsBySearchValue = filteredProducts.filter((search: Products) => {
    return search.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchValue);
  }) || filteredProducts;
  const currentProducts = productsBySearchValue.slice(firstIndex, lastIndex);
  const pages = Math.ceil(productsBySearchValue.length / productsPerPage);
  const numbers = [...Array(pages + 1).keys()].slice(1);

 const fetchData = async () => {
  axios.get('http://localhost:3030/products')
  .then((res: AxiosResponse<Products[]>) => {
    setProducts(res.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  };
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData()
    setSearchValue('');
  }, []);

  if(products.length === 0) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  const nextPage = () => {
    if (currentPage !== lastIndex) {
      setCurrentPage(curr => curr + 1);
    }
  };

  const prevPage = () => {
    if (currentPage !== firstIndex) {
      setCurrentPage(curr => curr - 1);
    }
  };

  const movePages = (id: number) => {
    setCurrentPage(id);
  };


  //Generate content type list
  const transformContentTypeintoList = [
    ...new Set(products.map((prod) => prod.contentType).flat()),
  ];

  const contentTypeList = transformContentTypeintoList
    .map((item) =>  [
        {
          label: item,
          value: item,
        },
      ])
    .flat();

  const handleSort = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setFilterValue(event?.target.value);
    //goto page 1 after sort
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  const handleTitleSearch = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const value = event.target.value;
        setSearchValue(value.toLowerCase());
        setCurrentPage(1)
  };

  const handleContentTypeSort = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    setContentTypeValue(value) 
    setCurrentPage(1);
  };

  const mapContentTypes = () => {
    return (
      <Select
        id="contentSelect"
        options={contentTypeList}
        datatestid={'contentTypeId'}
        onChange={handleContentTypeSort}
        defaultOption={'Select Content Type'}
        label={'Filter by Content type '}
      />
    );
  };
 

    const mapProducts = () => {
    if (currentProducts.length === 0) {
      return <NoResults />;
    } else {
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="searchContainer">
            <TextInput
              className="searchInput"
              placeholder="search by title"
              value={searchValue}
              datatestid={'searchId'}
              onChange={handleTitleSearch}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="container">
         
            <div className="filterContainer">
              <div>
                <Pagination
                  numbers={numbers}
                  currentPage={currentPage}
                  prevPage={prevPage}
                  movePages={movePages}
                  nextPage={nextPage}
                />
              </div>
              <div className="filter">
                {mapContentTypes()}
                <Select
                  id="SortSelect"
                  options={sortSelectOptions}
                  datatestid={'sortTestId'}
                  onChange={handleSort}
                  defaultOption={'Sort by'}
                  label={'Sort by '}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            {currentProducts.map((product: Products) => {
              return (
                <div className="item" key={product.id}>
            
                  <img
                  loading='lazy'
                    width={"100"}
                    height={"100"}   
                    src={product?.imgSet?.sm?.src}
                    alt=""
                  />
  
                  <div
                    aria-label={`Product${product.id}`}
                    tabIndex={0}
                    className="innerContainer">
                    <span className="text" tabIndex={0} aria-label={`Name`}>
                      Name: {product.title}
                    </span>
                    <span className="text" tabIndex={0} aria-label={`Price`}>
                      Price: {product.price}
                    </span>
                    <span
                      className="text"
                      tabIndex={0}
                      aria-label={` Stock level`}>
                      Stock level: {product.productType}
                    </span>
                  </div>
                </div>
              );
            })}
            <Pagination
              numbers={numbers}
              currentPage={currentPage}
              prevPage={prevPage}
              movePages={movePages}
              nextPage={nextPage}
            />
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <header className="App-header">
      <div className="container">{mapProducts()}</div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I would guess that `type.contentType` is undefined!

Comment: The error is telling you that `type.contentType` is `undefined`.  So what is `type`?  It would appear that `products` is an array which contains elements, of which at least one does not contain a property called `contentType`.  So what does `products` contain when this error occurs?  How does that differ from what you expected it to contain?  Why did you expect it to contain something different?

Comment: Please debug your code first and then think about what can cause the behavior you see during debugging (e.g. why certain variables have the values you observe in your debugger). The error message already tells you where to start debugging. If you then still can't solve it, add your findings from the debugging phase into your question and reformulate it to ask about the cause you identified.

Comment: Yes apologies I noticed this already but I should've mentioned that in my question, I'm trying to figure out how to test for an empty `contentType` as I know it requires a default value for the data to display but I'm unsure how to test for that.

Comment: @RogerBanks: Are you just looking for [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)?  For example: `type.contentType?.includes(contentTypeValue)`

Comment: is `[{title: "5-Minute Stories: In the Wild"}]` your product mock that came from the API? I don't see any ContentType, that's probably why you get an error. You have invalid Product mocks. But if you want to test what will happen when there are invalid products then you should probably check if products are valid in your component like with `const valid = products.every((type: Products) => type.contentType)` and return an error message so the component doesn't throw an error.

Comment: @David optional chaining worked thanks

Comment: @jcubic yes you're right, providing the proper data gave me what I wanted, thansk

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using optional chaining in order to avoid searching in the missing array:

```
products.filter((type: Products) => type.contentType?.includes(contentTypeValue))
```

In addition, you should use more correct naming in your methods and entities:

```
products.filter((product: Products) => product.contentTypes?.includes(contentTypeValue))
```